# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to put formatting 2 decimal in my code program and I get error "TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.**format**"

Here's the code:

```
new_pred = model.predict(sc.transform(np.array([[float(x) for x in request.form.values()]])))
new_preds = (new_pred > 0.5).astype(int)
```

and return it

```
pred1 = 'Accuracy  : {:.2f}%'.format(new_pred*100))
```

Please help me!

Comment: You are mixing the older `%` formatting with the new py3 `,format` style. Reread the python string formatting documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get 2 decimal by this: `np.printoptions()`

```
import numpy as np
with np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True):
    print(new_pred*100)
```

Link to doc [np.printoptions()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html)